# How can I get environment variables from docker compose in Quasar Framework?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, docker-compose, quasar-framework

I have the next docker-compose configuration

```
version: '3'

services:  
 frontend:
  image: frontend-image
  depends_on:
   - backend-image
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
   - OAUTH_CLIENT="client"
   - OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY="Client111"
   - BACKEND_HOSTNAME="localhost"
   - BACKEND_PORT="8080"
```

This is the frontend-image Dockerfile

```
FROM  quasarframework/quasar-org:1.0.0

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package.json /opt/app/package.json

RUN rm -r node_modules

RUN npm install

RUN npm -g install quasar-cli

COPY . /opt/app

EXPOSE 4000

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["quasar", "dev"]
```

But when I execute console.log(process.env) I'm only getting one property:

```
{NODE_ENV:"development"}
```

Everything on the front end is working OK, my unique problem is with environment variables.
My objective is to set different environment variables for different environments.

Docker version

```
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:11:19 2017
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:09:53 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Docker Compose Version

```
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
docker-py version: 2.6.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Comment: Docker environment variables were made for composing and building a project. They don't have any effect at runtime. If you need it for runtime, then you're going to have to pass in the environment variable manually or through a .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quasar lets you pass custom environment variables through `build.env` property of `quasar.conf.js`.

#### Quasar App CLI v2+

```js
{
    // ...
    build: {
        env: {
            OAUTH_CLIENT: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT,
            OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY),
            BACKEND_HOSTNAME: process.env.BACKEND_HOSTNAME,
            BACKEND_PORT: parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT),
        }
    }
}
```

You now will be able to use your env variables inside your quasar application:

```js
console.log(process.env.APP_OAUTH_CLIENT);
// note, that
console.log(process.env);
// won't work as you might expect
```

---

#### Quasar App CLI before v2

You can be as simple as:

```js
{
    // ...
    build: {
        env: {
            OAUTH_CLIENT: JSON.stringify(process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT),
            OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY),
            BACKEND_HOSTNAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_HOSTNAME),
            BACKEND_PORT: process.env.BACKEND_PORT, // this will be integer at runtime!
        }
    }
}
```

Or pass everything in bulk:

```js
{
    // ...
    build: {
        env: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(process.env)
            /* Filter variables which you want to pass to quasar, for example only pass variables starting with APP_ */
            .filter(([ key, value ]) => /^APP_/.test(key))
            /* Enquote strings so that they remain strings when inlined to source code by quasar */
            .map(([ key, value ]) => [ key, JSON.stringify(value) ])
        )
    }
}
```

You now will be able to use your env variables inside your quasar application:

```js
console.log(process.env);
console.log(process.env.APP_OAUTH_CLIENT);
```

A couple of notes, though

First, it is strongly advised to filter variables passed down to your quasar application, i.e. meaning to **public scope**.

vue-cli does a similar thing by default:

> Note that only `NODE_ENV`, `BASE_URL`, and variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle ... (from [vue-cli guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)).

Quasar doesn't embed anything out of the box, but let you have full control over what and how to embed using it's `build.env` config property.

Second, note that when you pass `{ BACKEND_HOSTNAME: "localhost" }` variable and then use it like `var h = process.env.BACKEND_HOSTNAME;` quasar statically **replaces** it with `localhost` **as is**, not trying to somehow serialize the value, so it evaluates to `var h = localhost`, which is not a valid JS and you will probably receive a syntax error. Instead, if you want to be on a safe side, I'd recommend to serialize all env values to strings with `JSON.stringify` when passing to quasar config, so that `var h = process.env.BACKEND_HOSTNAME;` becomes `var h = "localhost"`.

I also find it useful to define a dedicated module to deal with env variables:

```js
export default {
    oauthClient: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT,
    oauthClientKey: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY,
    backendHostname: process.env.BACKEND_HOSTNAME,
    backendPort: process.env.BACKEND_PORT,
    debug: process.env.DEBUG === 'true'
}
```

This way all your environment imports have a single entrance point.
Note however, that it doesn't provide [code stripping](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/handling-process-env#Stripping-out-code):

```js
import myenv from './myenv';
if (myenv.debug) {
    console.log('We are debugging something');
}
```

this code **never** will be stripped out. To use code stripping, you have to use `process.env.DEBUG === "true"` notation, so it is replaced as `"false" === "true"` by quasar and later stripped out with code bundlers as an unreachable code block.

Comment: This is partial answer of the question! He wants to pass the environment variable values from the docker-compose file is there a way to pass it?

Comment: There's no difference as to the source of envvars - you pass them in the exact same way. But if you meant to pass **all** the envvars, like in bulk, then, first of all, it's simple as `build: { env: process.env }`, but it is **strongly advised** that you never do that, because that would potentially leak **ALL** your server envvars to the public scope of your application. Instead, you explicitly specify what is available to the outside world - see the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

You can't get docker ENV from quasar app. Quasar app is client side application and runs on browser, so it doesn't have access to the container resource. We can use process.env.* in quasar is because Quasar make it up for convenient and these ENV in quasar are defined by webpack.

Hope this help

Comment: This is absolutely false! As you've said "ENV in quasar are defined by webpack" and this happens during build step, which is run on server and has access to environment and could be used, as you can see in @quasar/dotenv / @quasar/qenv or vue-cli. Vue-cli by default filters out all variables starting with `VUE_APP_` during build-time and populates them (via webpack) to webapp context. Quasar simply doesn't have such option out of the box.